# Skipped and duplicated line numbers in log4J output

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I've set up log4j but I've noticed strange output like this ( I would expect to see 0 1 2 3 4 as the line numbers) -

```
0    [main] DEBUG org.dnsdojo.ryanhost.GA.MuPlusOne.Genome  - 0011110101101010110110111011101111110001010001110011100011110111011001011100100100101001100110100000011100010100
2    [main] DEBUG org.dnsdojo.ryanhost.GA.MuPlusOne.Genome  - 112
2    [main] DEBUG org.dnsdojo.ryanhost.GA.MuPlusOne.Genome  - 0010100111111010110110010001000100000110110111111011011100101010011100011001111111111011110011001111010100100101
3    [main] DEBUG org.dnsdojo.ryanhost.GA.MuPlusOne.Genome  - 112
3    [main] DEBUG org.dnsdojo.ryanhost.GA.MuPlusOne.Genome  - 0101101000001010000001101000101001001000111111111110001010011001111011010101011010010000111000100011110010101100
3    [main] DEBUG org.dnsdojo.ryanhost.GA.MuPlusOne.Genome  - 112
```

Can anyone explain why this might be happening? 
    log4j.properties
    #define the console appender
    log4j.appender.consoleAppender = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

```
# now define the layout for the appender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# now map our console appender as a root logger, means all log messages will go to this appender
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, consoleAppender
```

Genome Class

```
package org.dnsdojo.ryanhost.GA.MuPlusOne;

import java.util.Random;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;


public class Genome
{
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Genome.class);
byte[] genome;
Random rng = new Random();
String genomeString = "";

public Genome ( int stringLength, int motorSet )
{
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
    genome = new byte[ stringLength * 7 * motorSet]; // stringLength depends on how many bytes you wish to have. For the arpibot this is dependant on the number of sensor readings taken
    for (int i = 0; i < genome.length; i++)
    {
        genome[i] = (byte)rng.nextInt(2);
        genomeString += genome[i];
    }
    logger.debug(genomeString);
    logger.debug(genomeString.length());
}

public byte[] getGenome()
{
    return genome;
}

public byte[] mutate (float mutationStep)
{
    return genome;                                  //placeholder
}

}
```

Driver Class

```
package org.dnsdojo.ryanhost.GA.MuPlusOne;

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Driver 
{
int populationSize = 0; //mu
int evaluationTime = 0; //tau measured in seconds
double reevaluationRate, mutationStep = 0;//rho = reevaluationRate, sigma = mutationStep
int numberOfSensors, numberOfMotors = 0;

ArrayList<Genome> population = new ArrayList<Genome>();

public Driver (int populationSize, int evaluationTime, double reevaluationRate, double mutationStep, int numberOfSensors, int numberOfMotors)
{
    this.populationSize = populationSize;
    this.evaluationTime = evaluationTime;
    this.reevaluationRate = reevaluationRate;
    this.mutationStep = mutationStep;
    this.numberOfSensors = numberOfSensors;
    this.numberOfMotors = numberOfMotors;

    for(int i = 0; i < populationSize; i++)
    {
        population.add (new Genome (numberOfSensors , numberOfMotors) );
    }
}

public static void main( String[] args)
{
    Driver gADriver = new Driver(100, 60 , 0.2, 0.2, 8, 2);
}

}
```

Comment: A few answers have been provided but this question is not clear. Whenever something is "other than expected" please define what WAS EXPECTED. "Can anyone explain why this might be happening?"

Comment: Sorry I would have thought this would have been clear from the "skipped and duplicated line numbers" in the question, indicating that I was expecting a sequential increment in the numbering. Edited question to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Javadoc page](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) states the following for the Pattern `%-4r`

> r - Used to output the number of milliseconds elapsed from the
>   construction of the layout until the creation of the logging event.

The `%-4` is saying use 4 spaces (padding) to write the information required by `r`. So what I'm guessing is your logs are coming one after the other so fast that they are only 1-2 milliseconds apart (the first number in your log statement). We can also deduce that the Pattern layout is constructed lazily, when you actually start logging things.

Comment: This could be what he meant but not sure. The pattern and output look okay: ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n ... if you look at the dash (-) and then what comes after is the output. This has nothing to do with everything before it. The %m is the message and %n is the newline.

Comment: I had assumed that the initial number was actually line numbers as I'm so used to reading notepad++ output. I had copy/pasted this properties file and did not realise it was showing the elapsed milliseconds which makes more sense. In retrospect this was a bad question but this answer allowed me to see that. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the logger (I have used log4j for 15 years).
It appears to be logging exactly the String that was sent to it.
Look at the code again and compare to what is expected.
The `Random` generator for `nextInt(2)` is looking for a value of 0-1 ...
Hence a string of 0's and 1's is logged.

```
for (int i = 0; i < genome.length; i++)
{
    genome[i] = (byte)rng.nextInt(2);
    genomeString += genome[i];
}
logger.debug(genomeString);
logger.debug(genomeString.length());
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he meant. Line number as in the start of his log statement.

Comment: The question was "strange output" ... implying something else was expected. Maybe he meant the first byte. Otherwise the pattern and output look as expected: ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n ... if you look at the dash (-) and then what comes after is the output. This has nothing to do with everything before it. The %m is the message and %n is the newline.